# accepted answers with many downvotes

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10416) has an accepted answer with currently 5 downvotes, so it looks that it's not a good answer after all. How can we encourage the asker to reconsider this accept?

Answer (score 1):

What you did: write a comment addressed at OP.

There's something else. Not everybody looks at the upvote/downvote breakdown, IIRC users with less than 1000 rep can't even see that. An answer may have 10 upvotes and 9 downvotes, so 1 vote will be displayed. I'm afraid that many users will only look at the accepted answer. 9 downvotes is *a lot*, and IMO should count more than 10 upvotes. Two down per downvote?

Comment: I dont think a comment on your answer will address the OP, but we can test, do you see this comment in your inbox @FedericoRusso? I did not get an autocomplete, so I doubt it. Please post on the question if you dont see this with your input, it is nice to let him know the status of his question has since changed, but in the end the poster gets to choose the accepted answer, but it is less rep than 2 upvotes. It also will draw attention to an incorrect answer, I am sure it would have many fewer downvotes if it were witting at the bottom of the list and not accepted.

Comment: @Kortuk: no, I didn't get notified. I agree with stevenvh, the 5 downvotes are much worse than the total result of -2, and these aren't shown. I'll write a comment to the question. Thanks.

Comment: @FedericoRusso, the user whom posted the answer also has the option to delete their own answer and get rid of all of that nasty rep loss. I would consider this the way that most answers that are incorrectly accepted can be rectified.

Comment: @Kortuk - currently 3 upvotes, 6 downvotes. Despite the smashing number of downvotes this earns him +3 x 10 + 15 - 6 x 2 = +33 points! Why would he delete it? Shouldn't downvotes have more effect?

Comment: @stevenvh, they look bad honestly, I have deleted when I was new for that reason. If you are doing everything only for the reputation number I think it is being done for the wrong reason. Reputation is a made up number that we attempt to use as a shortened resume on the site. Hopefully most people are here for the warm feeling you get when you help someone. Even if they answer is incorrect, which is displayed by the net number of up and down votes, the user is still taking part in the site and is getting some reward in privileges. 10k rep this way would be an issue, but 30, who cares.

Comment: @Kortuk - agreed about rep. I stated what I see as a problem in my answer: even though there may be a lot of those bad-looking downvotes they may hardly be visible. Who's curious enough to take a look at the up/downvotes breakdown?

Comment: @stevenvh, I consider it more of a fancy, if the answer has 2 upvotes but yours has 7 it is pretty clear which answer is better. In this case I dont think the answer is "wrong" but instead just lacks an actual answer.

Comment: @Kortuk - In that case shouldn't answers be ordered by votes, regardless of which answer was accepted? Listing the accepted answer first gives it extra credibility.

Comment: @stevenvh, extra credibility, as the signed answer that corrected the users issue, and increased review as the first think all experts will read, as you saw on this question.

Comment: I think most of the time the system works.  This is a unusual case where it failed and bad advice was given the stamp of approval.  I used upvotes, downvotes, and comments to do my little part in trying to rectify the situation.  Others obviously did too, and the problem seems have been largely cleared up.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to ding people for one or two downvotes, since those happen for random and sometimes wrong reasons.  We seem to have some occasional downvoting vandalism here too.  However, 3 or more downvotes isn't just vandalism or a mistake, that's a concensus.  In that case I can see the point to them causing a full upvote worth of rep loss.  Either way though, this seems to be a small problem on this site.  Earning 33 points for a bad answer feels wrong to me too, but it's also noise in the scheme of things.  That's less than 1/1000 the rep you and I each have.